# new Intl.NumberFormat 'de-DE' doesnt return what is expected

Tags: javascript, react-native, number-formatting

When I run `new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(11111111.45)` I get`€11,111,111.45` and I expect `€11.111.111,45`(as per documentation). I am using this in a react native app. Does anyone know why I may have this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Where/how do you run that? The latest versions of Firefox, Safari, Chrome all return `11.111.111,45 €`

Comment: It is iOS app. So I run it on an iPad simulator.

Comment: @Dai this is all the relevant code: `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(11111111.45));`